# Overleaf - editing citations via regular expression

Tags: overleaf

I need to add "." at the end of all my citation titles.

I want to use the Overleaf tool the works with `cmd+F` (`ctrl+F` in Windows), as it allows to change all the results of a search together.

Therefore the regular expression is title={.*.}, which should change to title={.*.}

How can I do it?

title={.*} works for the searching, but then I have to manually add "." to not lose the title.

Comment: ... okay, this is a regex question rather than a TeX question. Not sure if it's allowed here.

Comment: I was unsure as well. But then I saw the "overleaf" tag and I thought it was fine.

Comment: Anyway you will want to lookup "regex capturing group".

Comment: I found this https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Can_I_use_regular_expressions_for_%22replace_with%22%3F but it didn't work

Comment: Yes that one is the correct thing. (although sure it doesn't teach regex well, look for some regex tutorial too I guess?) what have you tried with that?

Comment: I tried my case. Namely, instead of /([a-z])-([a-z])/ I wrote title={.\*} and instead of /$1$2/ I wrote title={$1.}

Comment: You didn't have a capturing group. (read up on what it means.)

Comment: True, I added the parenthesis title={(.*)} and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Tom from Overleaf Support. Using `title=\{(.*[^.])\}` and `title={$1.}` should do the trick, but as pointed out, this is a question of using regex searches. (And sorry for the article being slightly wrong, you don't need the outer `/`s in our current interface.)

Comment: @yo' although possibly offtopic this helped me, maybe post it as an answer?